# How do I access the files in a deleted user account?

Tags: macos, user-account

`/Users/Abby` is the home folder of a user account that has been deleted. Check out the screenshot:

[image]

While logged in as `work` (which is no longer an account I use for work, but I can't be bothered to change the name of the home folder), the files in `/Users/Abby` are do-not-enter.

I want to get into them to see if I've left any stuff behind, but I can't log in as Abby (since the user has been deleted).

While we're here, I'm not completely sure how I managed to delete this user account without deleting its home folder (or putting its home folder in a `Deleted Users` folder). This all seems... quite odd.

I did all this user deletin' and messin' around in Lion and have since upgraded to Mountain Lion.

Comment: The answers below are spot on, but I just wanted to answer your last question. When you delete a user you're asked what you would like to do with the Home folder, one option (the default I believe) being keep it in its current location.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Here's a few different ways you can access the old user's files:*

---

- Recreate the deleted account, and log in with it:

  1. In **System Preferences > Users & Groups**, click the padlock icon and then the plus button to **create a new user**
  2. **name the User "Abby"** - the OS should ask you *if you want to use the existing home folder* - choose to do so
  3. from the Apple menu, choose "**Log out**"
  4. **log in as "Abby"** and you will have access to the old account again

---

- Use the "System Administrator" account to access the files:

  1. navigate to the folder "**/System/Library/CoreServices/**" and open "**Directory Utility.app**"
  2. Click the padlock
  3. in the "**Edit**" menu, choose "**Enable root user**"
  4. from the Apple menu, choose "**Log out**"
  5. **log in as "System Administrator"** (or "root") and you will have access to the files in "/Users/Abby"

---

- Change the permissions of the old home folder:

  1. **Right-click** the "**/Users/Abby**" folder and choose "**Get Properties**"
  2. Click the padlock at the very bottom of the "Get Info" window
  3. **Click the "+" button** at the very bottom of the "Get Info" window
  4. **Select your current account** from the users list
  5. **Give your current user** (at the very bottom of the "Get Info" window) to have "**Read & Write**" privs
  6. From the gear menu choose "**make (me) the owner**"
  7. From the gear menu choose "**Apply to enclosed items...**"

---

*If you want information on how this occurred, I just [answered a similar question yesterday](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60389/why-are-there-folders-in-users-of-already-deleted-users/60436#60436)*

Comment: Another way to create the System Administrator (root) user is via Terminal: `dsenableroot` will ask you for the current user's password (if admin), and then for a new root password twice.

Comment: An excellent set of solutions. I got in via method #1 and am making it permanently mine via method #3. Thank you for your help!

Comment: victoly! no problem